# Replace reserved characters in xml with escape strings

Tags: regex, xml, perl, sed

I have xml files which contains characters `<`,`>`,`&`. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <medi>bla bla >12 bla</medi>
  <diag>bla & bla <12</diag>
</test>
```

These characters are reserved for xml notation and should be replaced by escaping strings `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`. This holds also for quotes (" ->`&quot;`) and apostrophes (' -> `&apos;`).

Here is what I like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <medi>bla bla &gt;12 bla</medi>
  <diag>bla &amp; bla &lt;12</diag>
</test>
```

Usually, I use regular expression with perl or sed. But, sincerely, I did not succeed. The difficulty is to avoid replacing xml relevant characters like `<` and `>` and `&` of escape strings.

To make it clear what I mean I put a solution with perl which does not work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input  = $ARGV[0];
my $output = $ARGV[1];

open INPUT,  $input or die "Couldn't open file $input, $!";
open OUTPUT, ">$output" or die "Couldn't open file $output, $!";

my $rec;

while (<INPUT>) {

    $rec = $_;
    print $rec;

    $rec =~ s/(<medi>.*)<(.*<\/medi>)/$1&lt;$2/g;    
    $rec =~ s/(<medi>.*)>(.*<\/medi>)/$1&gt;$2/g;    
    $rec =~ s/(<medi>.*)&(.*<\/medi>)/$1&amp;$2/g;
    $rec =~ s/(<medi>.*)'(.*<\/medi>)/$1&apos;$2/g;
    $rec =~ s/(<medi>.*)"(.*<\/medi>)/$1&quot;$2/g;

    $rec =~ s/(<diag>.*)<(.*<\/diag>)/$1&lt;$2/g;    
    $rec =~ s/(<diag>.*)>(.*<\/diag>)/$1&gt;$2/g;    
    $rec =~ s/(<diag>.*)&(.*<\/diag>)/$1&amp;$2/g;
    $rec =~ s/(<diag>.*)'(.*<\/diag>)/$1&apos;$2/g;
    $rec =~ s/(<diag>.*)"(.*<\/diag>)/$1&quot;$2/g;

    print $rec;
    print OUTPUT $rec;
}
close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

This gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <medi>bla bla &amp;gt;12 bla</medi>
  <diag>bla & bla &amp;lt;12</diag>
</test>
```

What happens:

- The ampersand of `&gt;` was replaced with `&amp;` which is not intended
- Ampersand at `<diag> bla & bla ...`is not replaced

I'm sure there is a regexp which may solve this problem. But if there is a completely other way to make the xml well formed I am open for it.

Comment: As you won't be able to parse broken XML to DOM and operate in DOM domain, maybe you could use [Text::Balanced::extract_tagged()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced#extract_tagged)?

Comment: @StefanBecker Thanks for the link. Sincerly, I do need some time to understand how this works. If there is no way to get the well formed xml with regular expression I will try `extract_tagged()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have files that contain characters like '<', '>' and '&' in the text nodes, then you do not have XML files.

In order to fix this, you would need to parse the files with an XML parser. But it's likely that most XML parsers would refuse to parse these files as they aren't well-formed XML. It's possible that something like [XML::Lenient](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Lenient) could be useful here.

The correct approach is to go back to the source of these files and fix that process so that it generates well-formed XML files. If you are creating the files, then you need to fix the code that creates them. If someone is providing the files to you, then you need to go back to them and ask them to provide valid XML files.

Comment: I'm aware that I have not well formed xmls. That's why I want to replace the xml-characters with escape strings to get well formed xmls. The xmls are created from an external company where I do not have the possibility to change the xml-exporter. Thanks for `XML::Lenient`.

Comment: @giordano: *I do not have the possibility to change the xml-exporter* It's likely that somewhere there is a contract between your company and the company that is providing the "not-quite-XML" files. If that contract says that they will provide XML files then you have a reason to go back to them and ask them to fix the bug in their system. If they won't fix their system, then you should consider publicising the problem so other people are less likely to make the mistake of dealing with them.

Comment: There are of course solutions that "might" work given the files you currently have. But there is no way to guarantee it since you cannot tell 100% what is supposed to be structure and what is supposed to be text. Only whatever is generating this would know that.

Comment: @Grinnz I'm not really convinced. If I know what is the structure I could consider it in the regexp  as I did with the example code in Perl. If there are tags in tags (the same elements in elements), for example, <x><x></x></x> this would couse a problem (or a very ambitious regexp).

Comment: @giordano: And that's why your only guarantee of success is to go down the contractual route and get the bugs in your input fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd', by gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/&/&amp\;/g;s/</&lt\;/g;s/>/&gt\;/g;s/\x27/&apos\;/g;/xml ver/!s/\"/&quot\;/g' d
```

or " is \x22
if you assure it so